# How to debug an HTTP call error?

Tags: angular, cordova, http, debugging, client-server

I am developing a mobile app in TypeScript/JavaScript in Cordova with Angular. I am testing this app in Chrome by means of `ionic serve`.

One of my `GET` requests (let's refer to the URL as `X`) fails. I am observing the following symptoms:

- Chrome's network DevTools just show that the request has not been answered (no status code), and the *Preview* and *Response* tabs indicate *Failed to load response data*.
- The console shows two exceptions:

  - An unhandled promise rejection due to a "failing request" ("The request failed. Please check your network or server configuration.").
  - An uncaught exception in a promise.

[image: screenshot of error messages]

As far as I can see, these errors just reach deeply into `polyfills.js` (a minified JavaScript file apparently automatically generated in the course of transforming TypeScript code into JavaScript) and originate from the command that sends the request itself.

- When I send a request to `X` from another tab in the same browser, one that is running a web-based (i.e. non-Cordova) AngularJS application, the request goes through without any issues.
- A very similar request to `Y` (same server, same web service, just another function) can be executed flawlessly also from the Cordova application.

**How can I find out what's the issue here?**

Obviously, I see that the error message suggests to "check [my] network or server configuration", but where/what exactly can I check? As evidenced by the request to `X` from another tab and the request to `Y` from the same Cordova app, the network connection itself and the target web service are fine.

Could it be related to response size/time, as `X` returns quite a large package of bulk data (in one exemplary call, 14.5 MB of JSON returned after some 2.5 minutes))?

Comment: error is in polyfills.js file.. i don't know why are you using it but its not the part of cordova may  be you are using 3rd party js.. just remove it and then make the call does http call goes through ??

Comment: @Anuj.T: `polyfills.js` is a file filled with unintelligible minimized JavaScript generated automatically in the course of interpreting the TypeScript source code.